# Same for loop, giving out two different results using .write()

Tags: python-3.x

this is my first time asking a question so let me know if I am doing something wrong (post wise)

I am trying to create a function that writes into a .txt but i seem to get two very different results between calling it from within a module, and writing the same loop in the shell directly. The code is as follows:

```
def function(para1, para2): #para1 is a string that i am searching for within para2. para2 is a list of strings
    with open("str" + para1 +".txt", 'a'. encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    #opens a file with certain naming convention

        n = 0
        for word in para2:
            if word == para1:
                file.write(para2[n-1]+'\n')
                print(para2[n-1]) #intentionally included as part of debugging
            n+=1

function("targetstr". targettext) 
#target str is the phrase I am looking for, targettext is the tokenized text I am
#looking through. this is in the form of a list of strings, that is the output of
#another function, and has already been 'declared' as a variable
```

when I define this function in the shell, I get the correct words appearing. However, when i call this same function through a module(in the shell), nothing appears in the shell, and the text file shows a bunch of numbers (eg: 's93161), and no new lines.

I have even gone to the extent of including a print statement right after declaration of the function in the module, and commented everything but the print statement, and yet nothing appears in the shell when I call it. However, the numbers still appear in the text file.

I am guessing that there is a problem with how I have defined the parameters or how i cam inputting the parameters when I call the function.

As a reference, here is the desired output:

‘She

Ashley

there

Kitty

Coates

‘Let

let

that

PS: Sorry if this is not very clear as I have very limited knowledge on speaking python

Comment: Why don't you debug your own code? Did you try to debug it before posting? You'll have to learn to do that, eventually. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions

Comment: [StackOverflow Question Checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: yes i did. As mentioned in the code. Perhaps is it not the most rigorous of debugging, which I apologize for. I am sorry I am not asking the type of programming questions that excite you, since I have limited knowledge, just know that if this is the type of attitude towards people who are earnestly trying to learn code would not help grow a community of people who love doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to issue. Turns out that I need to close the shell and restart everything before the compiler recognizes the changes made to the function in the module. Thanks to those who took a look at the issue, and those who tried to help.